# Collecting a list of fields that have been updated when django saves a model record

Tags: django

I am creating a "What's New" section that lists all of the database changes in the last day.  Off of a recent [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019732/query-field-across-multiple-django-models), I want use post_save or pre_save to capture the fields that have been altered when Django saves a model record.  I will save this data in another table (time-stamped).  I know this is possible because one can observe the behavior in the admin application - it identifies which fields have been altered).

As best I can tell, the admin application utilizes forms.changed_data.  But using post_save or pre_save does not receive any forms information.

Is there an efficient way to determine which fields have been changed?  Do I have to compare each field in the model to it's current value (pre_save) to determine this list?  Any help (with code examples) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216317/django-before-a-model-is-updated-id-like-to-look-at-its-previous-attributes/3216444#3216444). Basically you could cache your fields when initializing the object, and then in the `post_save` signal you can compare every field with the cached value ... or write a method that does the comparison, and only returns the fields that have been modified.